# how to increase ubuntu's performance(overall)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, performance, system

I have a 1Tb hdd(internal in laptop) which I have divided in 750Gb (windows partition) and 100Gb ubuntu partition , my ubuntu OS is quite dull(over all performance including boot and multitasking) after 2 updates from 14.04 to 14.04 and 14.10 to 15.04. Now my main question is Should I reinstall by formatting and repartitioning drive giving 1Tb space to ubuntu entirely, since I want to use only ubuntu operating system. If no then how should I increase my system performance with ubuntu (and I seriously want to get rid of windows).

PS: (other hardware configuartion) Samsung Laptop with 6Gb ram and Quad core (4 * 2.5Ghz Intel i5 processor) Windows 7 Home Premium Preloaded with other recovery software's  (which might affect system performance).

Comment: The HDD mentioned in question is actually internal HDD in my laptop, not a SSD

Comment: @MiHa - I am sorry I don't have SSD it is just another type of HDD

Answer (score 0):

- I would format the drive completely
- Do clean reinstallation, I don't upgrade Ubuntu to newer versions as it slows the OS down, also it goes wrong sometimes... That's the habit from times, when I was using Windows... and it really helps
- Install preload:

`sudo apt-get install preload`

*Preload is a daemon – a background service, in other words – that monitors the applications you use on your computer. It learns the libraries and binaries you use and loads them into memory ahead of time so the applications start faster.*

- remove unnecessary startup applications
- use lighter DE

*I have bad experience with installing additional DE to existing one. For example when you have Unity and install KDE alongside it... it went always wrong on my PC, weird glitches appeared etc. SO I would suggest downloading Ubuntu flavours as `Xubuntu` or `Ubuntu MATE` with XFCE and MATE as their default DE.*

- decrease swappiness (when using SSD, this is the "must have"), deault value is 60... if you go to for example 30, Ubuntu will write more data to RAM rather then SWAP on HDD, which is slow.

`gksu gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`

*look for* `vm.swappiness=some value`, *if that line doesn't exist, you can simply add this line as:*`vm.swappiness=value you want`

[image]

**And really you will help yourself if you buy SSD!**

Comment: how to decrease swapiness, and can you suggest any light DE.

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184217/why-most-people-recommend-to-reduce-swappiness-to-10-20) question regarding `vm.swappiness`.